# Dojo FilteringSelect shows up as plain text box

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-server

I am just beginning to try out Dojo for use with ESRI ArcGIS Server. I have tried a few tutorials and I'm having a problem with the Dojo FilteringSelect Dijit.

Relevant sections of my code:

```
<script>
  dojo.require("esri.map");
  dojo.require("esri.tasks.query");
  dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
  dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");

  var map;

  function init() {
    map = new esri.Map("mapDiv",{
      basemap: "streets",
      center: [-80.94, 33.646],
      zoom: 8
    });
    dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", initFunctionality);
  }

  function initFunctionality(map) {
    //build query task
    var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3");

    //build query filter
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    query.outFields = ["NAME", "POP2000", "POP2007", "POP00_SQMI", "POP07_SQMI"];
    query.where = "STATE_NAME = 'South Carolina'";
    query.outSpatialReference = {"wkid":102100};

    var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate();
    infoTemplate.setTitle("${NAME}");
    infoTemplate.setContent( "<b>2000 Population: </b>${POP2000}<br/>"
                         + "<b>2000 Population per Sq. Mi.: </b>${POP00_SQMI}<br/>"
                         + "<b>2007 Population: </b>${POP2007}<br/>"
                         + "<b>2007 Population per Sq. Mi.: </b>${POP07_SQMI}");

    map.infoWindow.resize(245,105);

    //Can listen for onComplete event to process results or can use the callback option in the queryTask.execute method.
    dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", function(featureSet) {
      map.graphics.clear();

      var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,255,255,0.35]), 1),new dojo.Color([125,125,125,0.35]));

      //QueryTask returns a featureSet.  Loop through features in the featureSet and add them to the map.
      dojo.forEach(featureSet.features,function(feature){
        var graphic = feature;
        graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
        graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);

        map.graphics.add(graphic);
      });
    });

    queryTask.execute(query);
  }

  function initLineID(features) {
    var lineIdObjects = [];
    dojo.forEach(features.features, function(feature) {
        lineIdObjects.push({"name": feature.attributes.field_name});
    });

    //Build the appropriate data object for our data component
    var data = {
          "identifier": "name",
          "items": lineIdObjects
    }

    //bind the data object to the datastore
    var lineDataStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: data});

    //bind the data store to the FilteringSelect component
    dijit.byId("lineid").store = lineDataStore;
 } 

  dojo.ready(init);
</script>
```

as well as

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" 
       id="lineid"
       searchAttr="name" 
       name="widgetName" 
       onChange="doSomething(this.value)">
```

The challenge I face is that the resulting page only shows a basic

```
<input type="text">
```

box. Anyone know why this is? Thanks.

Comment: had taken out dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", initLineID) for troubleshooting purposes but added it back in and have the same problem.

Comment: Which version of dojo you are using? Do you set parseOnLoad to true?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you haven't configured a theme.  You can do so by adding stylesheets and modifying the body element.

In this example, I am using the claro theme.

```
<link href="PATH_TO/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="PATH_TO/dijit/themes/dijit.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="PATH_TO/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Add the theme name to the body element.

```
<body class="tundra">
```

Comment: I am using the style sheet they supply for use in the tutorials. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.0/js/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

Comment: Do you have the tundra class on your body element?  I updated m,y example to use the tundra theme and not the claro theme.

Answer (score 0):

parseOnLoad was set to false. For my future reference, why would I want to leave it at false?